# TimePicker Android Custom Hour

Tags: android, timepicker

Is there a way to set a larger value on the TimePicker widget in Android?(larger than 24) I want to use it for something other than clock time.

Answer (score 1):

If your minimum SDK is 11 or greater (Honeycomb), then you can simply use the [NumberPicker class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html).

If you are using a lower minumum SDK, try [this library project that emulates NumberPicker](https://github.com/mrn/numberpicker).

Answer (score 0):

try to override TimePicker Class, then I think you can able to do that thing in your custom `TimePicker`,